# How to add custom region names on a leaflet.js map

Tags: javascript, json, dictionary, leaflet, geojson

I have created a map using leaflet.js which takes data sets from a geojson file.

Since the map is offline, it does not show the region names or tiles. I want the names to be taken from my geojson file (feature.properties.name) and shown on each region (there are only 30 regions) permanently as simple text but not in the form of tooltip.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

```js
  var map = L.map('map').setView([65.5, 29.9], 2);
    }; 

function style(feature) {
return {
    weight: 2,
    opacity: 1,
    color: '#AAAAAA',
    dashArray: '3',
    fillOpacity: 0.7,
    fillColor: getColor(feature.properties.density)
};
}
geojson = L.geoJson(statesData, {
   style: style,
   onEachFeature: onEachFeature
}).addTo(map);
```

```html
<div id="map" class="m-auto"></div>
<?php include "../regions-map.php"; ?>
```

Comment: I did see someone else had a similar map and had added custom names which were being shown as tooltips when you would hover the mouse on regions. But I want the names to be visible all the times not just on hovering as tooltips.

Comment: You can pass the option `permanent: true` to tooltips

Comment: Thank you but the tooltips occupy too much space on regions. I want only text.